# VLOOKUP & TEXTJOIN - Return data from 2 columns, and join them into a single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, flatten, textjoin

How can I use VLOOKUP, and return 2 columns of data joined into 1 column?

- Solution must be ARRAYFORMULA compatible.

Here is a **current working formula** that will return the first & last name in a different column.

`=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:C,{2,3},FALSE)`

Here is a **non-working formula** How do I fix this formula to make it return {2,3} in a single column?

`=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:C,TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, {1,2}),FALSE)`

**Goal:** I would like to add a formula so when the ID is entered in the Employee Lookup tool, it will return the first & last name in the same cell.

### Sheet1 - Employee Database

| ID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x11111 | John | Doe |
| x22222 | Sarah | Smith |

### Sheet2 - Employee Lookup by ID tool

| ID | First&LastName |
| --- | --- |
| x11111 | =VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:C,TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, {1,2}),FALSE) |
| x22222 | Sarah Smith |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet1!A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))),,9^9)))
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly! Thanks Player0.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your input data before you search for it in `VLOOKUP()`

using this conversion `{Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!B2:B&""&Sheet1!C2:C}` your Employee Database will change to

[image]

this is how it will look in the formula
`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2:A,{Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!B2:B&" "&Sheet1!C2:C},2,FALSE))`

Comment: This worked great too! Thanks for the alternative. It's easier to read too (as a novice spreadsheet user)